# AngularJS using ng-click inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, ionic-framework

I can't get ng-click to work, I'm trying to pass an url to it inside a div so when the user clicks it goes to the next page, but when I click on the div I can see that it is getting the right link but instead of going to the next page it returns to the home.

```
<div ng-repeat="contatosCliente in contatos" class="conteudo" type="item-link" ng-click="urlcontato('#/app/contatos/' + contatosCliente.contatos_id)">
                     {{contatosCliente.nome}}
                    <i class="ion-ios-arrow-right" style="border: none; padding-right: 11px"></i>

                </div>
```

And my controller:

```
 $scope.urlcontato = function ( path ) {
            $location.path( path );
        };
```

Comment: yes I'm 100% sure @bioball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$location.path` should be called with just a forward slash, without that hash.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

```
<div ng-repeat="contatosCliente in contatos" class="conteudo" type="item-link" ng-click="urlcontato('/app/contatos/' + contatosCliente.contatos_id)">
```

And you should check to make sure that your view is bound to your controller. Add some logging in your function, or use a debugger statement, to make sure that `urlcontato` is being called.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly path should always begin with a forward slash (/) if not it is automatically appended. Remove the # and it should work

```
<div ng-repeat="contatosCliente in contatos" class="conteudo" type="item-link" ng-click="urlcontato('/app/contatos/' + contatosCliente.contatos_id)">
                 {{contatosCliente.nome}}
                <i class="ion-ios-arrow-right" style="border: none; padding-right: 11px"></i>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the ionic framework uses [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) for routing, you should do it this way:

```
$scope.urlcontato = function ( state ) {    
    $state.go(state);
}
```

Of course, you have to inject the $state service in your Controller (or directive).

For a default link in your html-code, you should use

```
<a ui-sref="yourstate">Linktitle</a>
```

For more information, see [this Navigation and Routing Article](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/)